# itemprop="offers" shows incomplete microdata error if no price tag

Tags: microdata

Is it possible to have the tag `<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">` but no  `<itemprop="price" class="uc-price">` tag?

I don't want to show the price if the item is out of stock. I just want to use the tag `<link itemprop="availability" href="schema.org/OutOfStock" />` 
but I get an 'incomplete microdata with schema.org' error.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rich Snippets / Micro Data for Products: Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955572/rich-snippets-micro-data-for-products-error-incomplete-microdata-with-schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Google Structured Data Testing Tool? I don't see this error.
Anyway there is common way of [using "meta"](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing) tags for elements you want to be hidden.