# Rich Snippets / Micro Data for Products: Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm getting an 'Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.' message when testing the markup with Google's testing tool (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e2bf685980a2f0ffadd5c52b2d5f).

I've simplified my code as much as possible, am I missing a certain 'required' type to get rid of this error? This is the only data I have available on my product pages at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="productdetail">
<img itemprop="image" src="testimage.jpg" width="300" height="300" name="multi" alt="Test" />
<h1 itemprop="name">Product Name</h1>
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="convertprice">
    <span itemprop="price">£2.00</span>
</span>
<p itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="stock"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" content="In Stock" />In Stock</p>
<div class="tab_info" id="tab1">
    <p itemprop="description" class="invtdesc2">This is where the product description will be!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this cryptic error is triggered because you're missing a price on the 2nd Offer. The following markup works without errors for me:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="productdetail">
    <img itemprop="image" src="testimage.jpg" width="300" height="300" name="multi" alt="Test" />
    <h1 itemprop="name">Product Name</h1>
    <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="convertprice">
        <span itemprop="price">£2.00</span>
    </span>
    <p itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="stock">
    <span itemprop="price">£2.00</span><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" content="In Stock" />In Stock</p>
    <div class="tab_info" id="tab1">
        <p itemprop="description" class="invtdesc2">This is where the product description will be!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

We're working on giving more informative error messages. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, what I did instead was get rid of the second offer altogether and put the the closing span tag to include the Stock availability in the first offer.

It might be worth highlighting necessary data on schema.org.

Comment: Glad that helped you. The challenge with documenting this is that schema.org is a coalition of search engines and each one can have different sets of required properties. Google documents which properties we require for rich snippets (eg. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750) in our webmaster help center. Likewise, Bing described which properties they require on their site (eg. http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/products-and-offers-markup-138d0977).

Comment: just got same error for product with no offers. offer availability= out_of_stock. fixed by adding dummy price=0 and pricecurrency=RUR